# Get Page Views via Hubspot API

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm

My Data Science team is trying to pull Hubspot info into their data visualization platform via Hubspot's API.

They're telling me that they can't find the information fora contact's pageview anywhere. I've searched the documentation for the API, contacted Hubspot Support (who told me they can't help with the API), and spent hours googling but I can't find any information on this.

Does the API simply not provide that information? I know it's collected, because I can see page views in a specific contact's timeline...so why can't I access it via API?

Has anyone overcome this challenge in the past or does anyone have any advice?

I should mention that I'm about 10% literate when it comes to anything code related...so I could just be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP in your API, then you should be able to find the number of page views here:

```
$objHubSpot->properties->hs_analytics_num_page_views->value
```

(where `$objHubSpot` is the name of the HubSpot object returned through API)

If you want to know the actual URL of the visited pages, then keep in mind that HubSpot only keeps a record of the last few URLs.